# CSS: Address @media subclass

Tags: css

I would like to change the following two style settings in the `@media` class. I am failing to find the right classes. The subclasses `.col-md` change their numbering throughout the document.

I am a CSS noob and have never dealt with a `@media` class so far (is it even a 'class' because of the @ tag?).
I searched the site but I am quite lost since I do not really know how to formulate my problem.

What is the correct way to set `margin-left: 10%` and `width: 80%`?

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: @OmprakashArumugam yes, bootstrap 3.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT based on comment:**

If what you want is to impact all `.col-md` disregarding numbers, you can use an **[attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)**:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  [class*='col-md'] {
      margin-left: 10%;
      width: 80%;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you wish to impact only the classes `.col-md-6` & `.col-md-offset-3` as you have included you can do:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-offset-3 {
      margin-left: 10%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
      width: 80%;
  }
}
```

This means, that the styles applied inside the @media query, will only work on media viewports with a minimum `width` of `992px` and above.

Make sure you set these at the end of your custom stylesheet which should be loaded after bootstrap styles.

[You can find more info on @media querys here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I thought using the exact same code would only apply to specific media files due to the numbers `3` and `6` in the subclass but it works for all media elements in my document.

Comment: You are welcome, it should impact on all elements with `.col-md-6` & `.col-md-offset-3` classes.

Comment: pat-s, I went through your question again and based on your comment, I included another example which seems to be closer to what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-offset-3 {
     margin-left: 10%;
    }

    .col-md-6 {
     width: 80%;
    }
}
```

`@media` is called a media query.  The CSS which needs to be applied when the condition is met all goes between curly braces following the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use col-sm for scrren size between >=768px and <992px.
For eg.,

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
```

In the above eg col-md-* will only affect when the screen size is >=992px and <1200, col-sm-* when >=768 and <992. For more  [info.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Regarding media query, It's like a break point.
For eg.,

```
p { font-size: 16px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    p { font-size: 12px; }
}
```

In the above example, p tag will have font-size of 12px only on screen size less than 480px. On all other devices it will have font-size of 16px. For more [info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)